# Pasar valores a un componente hijo de manera bidireccional

Tags: angular

Tengo 3 componentes,1 padre y 2 hijos.

**Componente padre:**

```
<p-tabView [(activeIndex)]="index">
  <p-tabPanel header="Child1">
    <app-child1 [person]="person.data1"></app-child1>
  </p-tabPanel>
  <p-tabPanel header="Child2">
    <app-child2 [person]="person.data2"></app-child2>
  </p-tabPanel>


person: any = {};
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.personService.getPerson(this.id).then(obj => this.person= obj);
}
```

**Componente Child1:**

```
@Input()
person: any;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.person= {age: 0};
}

<p-inputNumber [(ngModel)]="person.age" ></p-inputNumber>
```

**Componente Child2:**

```
@Input()
person: any;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.person= {adress: [{number:0}, {number:0}]};
}

<p-inputNumber disabled [(ngModel)]="person.age" ></p-inputNumber>
<p-inputNumber (ngModel)]="person.adress[0].number" ></p-inputNumber>
<p-inputNumber (ngModel)]="person.adress[1].number" ></p-inputNumber>
```

Me gustaría que si el valor de `age` en Child1 cambia, automáticamente se refleje el cambio en Child2.

Comment: Debes apoyarte en [`EventEmitter`](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) para lo que deseas hacer. Si compartes el código de los componentes padre e hijo podría ayudarte a adaptar el código.

Comment: acabo de añadir el código de los componentes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisando el código que has compartido parece que resolver tu problema es mucho más sencillo de lo que imaginaba.

Puedes hacerlo transfiriendo los datos originales a los hijos y no realizar ni copias ni modificaciones de dichos datos en ellos.

El principal problema que sufres es que desde el hijo 2 no puedes acceder a la propiedad real del padre llamada `person.age`, ya que has sobreescrito el valor de `person` dentro del componente por el contenido de `person.data2` del padre.

Para solucionarlo tendrías dos opciones:

- Enviar el contenido completo de `person` a cada hijo y acceder a los datos de `data1` o `data2` según se necesite dentro de ellos.
- Usar `{ address: person.data2.address, age: person.data1.age }` en `[person]` del hijo 2.

Esa última solución es la adoptada en el código que te muestro.
Ejemplo:

```
<app-child2
  [person]="{
    address: person.data2.address,
    age: person.data1.age
  }"
></app-child2>
```

Además, fíjate que en el código que te muestro a continuación que he eliminado todas las asignaciones que hacías en los hijos.

### Componente Child 1

He eliminado el método `ngOnInit()` en el que sobre escribías el valor de `person`.

```
export class Child1Component {
  constructor() { }

  @Input()
  person: any;
}

<p-inputNumber [(ngModel)]="person.age" ></p-inputNumber>
```

### Componente Child 2

He eliminado el método `ngOnInit()` en el que sobre escribías el valor de `person`.

```
export class Child2Component {
  constructor() { }

  @Input()
  person: any;
}

<p-inputNumber disabled [(ngModel)]="person.age" ></p-inputNumber>
<p-inputNumber (ngModel)]="person.address[0].number" ></p-inputNumber>
<p-inputNumber (ngModel)]="person.address[1].number" ></p-inputNumber>
```

### Componente padre

En este componente he cambiado la manera en la que envío los datos al componente Child 2 para que tenga acceso a la edad y a la dirección sin tener que hacer grandes cambios en el propio componente hijo:

```
export class AppComponent {
    person = {
        data1: { age: 40 },
        data2: { address: [ { number: 0 }, { number: 0 } ], }
    };
}

<p-tabView [(activeIndex)]="index">
  <p-tabPanel header="Child1">
    <app-child1 [person]="person.data1"></app-child1>
  </p-tabPanel>
  <p-tabPanel header="Child2">
    <app-child2
      [person]="{
        address: person.data2.address,
        age: person.data1.age
      }"
    ></app-child2>
  </p-tabPanel>
</p-tabView>
```

---

Puedes ver una versión en línea del código en la siguiente URL:

- [https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-yonath-j4e2br](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-yonath-j4e2br?file=/src/app/app.component.ts)

---

PD: Tal y como has desarrollado tu código, desde el punto de vista de los hijos el contenido de `person` será el que pases a través del atributo del componente con el mismo nombre, por lo que para el componente hijo 1 será `person.data1` y para el 2 será `person.data2`.

Creo que lo más coherente hubiera sido pasar el contenido de `person` completo o bien haber llamado de manera diferente al atributo.

Edición:

Para generar un campo de formulario por cada elemento de `address` de manera dinámica recomiendo hacer uso de un bucle [`NgFor`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgFor) usando uno de estos dos métodos:

**Repetir un componente y su contenido:**

```
<p-inputNumber
  *ngFor="let address of person.address"
  [(ngModel)]="address.number"
></p-inputNumber>
```

**Repetir todo lo encapsulado:**

```
<ng-template ngFor let-address [ngForOf]="person.address">
    <input [(ngModel)]="address.number" /><br />
</ng-template>
```

Comment: el problema lo tenia que estaba inicializandolo en cada hijo y me daba error de ctx. El caso es que en el padre inicializar pero en data2, en vez de tener dos "address" tengo N y esa depende del resultado q me devuelva el API, ¿alguna forma óptima que pueda hacerlo?

Comment: Claro, debes usar un bucle [`NgFor`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgFor). Edito el ejemplo que te enlacé para hacerlo mediante bucles y no mediante HTML estático.

Comment: Edición hecha, espero que te sea de ayuda :)

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, justo lo hice pero usando ngif y despues ngfor, no conocia la etiqueta ng-template, es posible que pueda modificar tu ejemplo ahi arriba y ver si se puede mejorar ?

Comment: Claro que sí. Puedes modificar el código para probar lo que necesites. Si inicias sesión puedes hacer una bifurcación (fork) y guardar tu propia versión del código.